# ASCX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to post data in .ASCX ? I guess NO ! If so, how I can accomplish this ? Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I am planning to create TABs in asp.net mvc page. Each and every tab will have different functionality with CREATE/EDIT/DELETE operations. I was thinking that I can create .ASCX and do RenderPartial in .ASPX. But we can't do post in .ASCX ? Is there any other way to do this ? Please let me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mgroves and andymeadows are talking about is simply this;

In your view;

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialControl"); %>
```

In your partial control, maybe;

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDatabase_Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)) {%>

    <%= Html.TextBox("MyField", Model.MyField %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitButton" />

<% } %>
```

In your controller;

```
public ActionResult UpdateDatabase_Action(FormCollection collection)
{
    MyFormViewModel fvm = new MyFormViewModel();
    TryUpdateModel(fvm);

    //do something with you data
}
```

Rinse, lather and repeat for each other action / partial control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider JSON to do this as then you can do a partial postback instead of full postback to a controller action.

Much better user experiance.

Answer (score 0):

With MVC, you don't post to files, you post to controller actions.  So you can have forms anywhere you want in your views.

Comment: ^^What he said.  Each control can have it's own form -- or multiple -- and post to any controller it chooses.  If we're missing the point, please elaborate or provide sample code.